# Control usage rights in Google image search

Tags: google, copyright, google-image-search

Can anyone explain what you need to do for your website images to get them to either show as **Creative Commons licenses** or **Commercial & Other licences** under Google Images Usage Rights filter?

[image: Commercial & Other Licences]

Is it scheme code setting this?

Googling for the answer only brings back results on what you can and can't use from Google images.